# Lamb-Chaplygin dipole

Tags: fluid-dynamics, specific-reference, dipole, vortex

There is an interesting issue of hydrodynamics: whirlpools.

I want to learn about the [Lamb-Chaplygin dipole](http://www.google.com/search?q=Lamb+Chaplygin+vortex+dipole+2d+Euler+equations).

Lamb-Chaplygin dipole corresponds to a steady solution of the two dimensional Euler equations.

Can someone know where I can find a full development of Lamb-Chaplygin dipole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is relevant: V.V. Meleshko and G.J.F. van Heijst, "On Chaplygin's investigations of two-dimensional vortex structures in an inviscid fluid," J. Fluid Mech. 272, 157-182, 1994 . While their outline may be less than "full", their bibliography looks comprehensive.

Comment: thank you, I just want to be sure. the solution is found in this document? http://ics.org.ru/doc?pdf=875&dir=e

Comment: Looks like that.

Comment: thank you very much! is the answer found in all of the pages (220-230) or just between 220 to 226?

Comment: I believe the answer is at pp. 219-225. The following commentary seems to add some details for the case of circular vortex motion, although this case is also handled in Chaplygin's paper, although briefly.

Comment: Hi again.. in the document that you posted here, this is the answer for the both equations?
because I see that there are two equations.. please take a look in page number 11: http://www.asp.ucar.edu/pdfp/doc/mike.pdf

thank you so much!!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "two equations". On page 11 of your latest reference (LR), the solution is given for the area within and outside the cylinder, but together these equations on p. 11 of LR give just one solution in the entire 2D plane. You can find the same equations forming the same single solution in your earlier reference (ER) at page 219 (equation (1) - outside the cylinder) and pages 219-220 (within the cylinder - equation (3) and the unnumbered second equation after Fig.1).

Comment: thank you and sorry that I don't understand.
I try to ask you the question in other words:
in page 11, there is the Lamb_Chaplygin dipole.
there are two cases: the first one is: r<=R and the second is: r > R. in your ER, there is a solution for both cases, right?

Comment: please answer me.. this was my last question..

Comment: Well, in the reference quoted in my answer, there is indeed a solution for both cases, although it is somewhat sketchy. I also noted that the solution outside the cylinder is somewhat different from that in mike.pdf file (the solutions in the other two references seem to coincide).

Comment: thanks! so I want these pages of the book in the reference quoted in your answer. this book is for free? or I have to rent him via: 
http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=419528

Comment: I don't know if you can get it for free. It looks like the journal is rather well-known, so maybe you can find it in a (university) library or use an inter-library loan. Or, maybe you just don't need it, as you have the text of Chaplygin's article.

Comment: thank you! I bought it and the solution is great for me! thank you very much!

Comment: is there a way to let you my two bronze badges?

Comment: Don't mention it - I learned something interesting myself.

Comment: hi again and sorry that I bother you.
I have the reference quoted in your answer (is named: link1): https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3-t1lLIJWOLc2NmT1RIWV9HOWs/edit?usp=sharing&pli=1

and have my reference (is named: link2): http://ics.org.ru/doc?pdf=875&dir=e

can you tell me please on which pages (and of which link) the answer is found? I think that: link1: 166-174, contains the link2: 219-225. so is the answer found at link1: 166-174? thank you and I'm very sorry about all my questions, I just need a proof for Lamb-Chaplygin dipole, it's very important for me that I paid this document.

Comment: In the paper quoted in my answer (I was not able to open your link1), the solution is at pp. 219-221. In link2, it's at pp. 158-159 and 166-167.

Comment: I think you confused the names of the links, but I understand. thank you so much!!! thanks!!! :]]

Comment: wow, I just now got an email: "Your bounty on the question …

Lamb-Chaplygin dipole

… ends in 23 hours. Please review the answers. If you feel one of them deserves your bounty, award it by clicking the bounty icon to the left of the answer"

I was sure that I awarded it to you while I marked that your answer is the best, but now I understand that it didn't. so I press the "+100". I hope you got it :] thanks for everything!